# Android read SMS history

Tags: android, sms, history

I found a way to read the call log, e.g. incoming call, phone number, duration, etc. Now I am looking for something similar for SMS. How can I read that history for SMS? I don't need the content of the SMS only the date and the target phone number. Any idea?

Thanks,
A.

Comment: found some tables where the data is stored, but most of the columns don't mean anything to me. It is a bit guessing. Not sure if that will lead to a solution. And after all not sure if that is available like this on all devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API for "SMS history" in the Android SDK, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source Cordova 2.2.0 example app showing use of a Cordova plug-in for Android to read SMS inbox and sent messages.  It uses some undocumented features of Android 4.2.

https://github.com/DavidWalley/CordovaPlugin_AndroidSmsRead

Hope you can use it.